# Digits sum of prime number, written in ternary system

Tags: prime-numbers

Recently, I've observed that if we write a prime number (greater than 2) with base 3 (in the ternary system), then the sum of digits will be an odd number.

Is this previously been observed? Is this useful somehow?

Examples: (decimal prime, ternary representation, a sum of ternary digits)

```
3       10                      1
17      122                     5
47      1202                    5
97      10121                   5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All odd numbers have a ternary digit sum that is odd, as it is the sum of an odd number of powers of $3$. All even numbers have a ternary digit sum which is even.  This is true in other odd bases too.

Your result follows from the fact that $2$ is the only even prime and you have excluded it.